# Интерпретатор выдаёт ошибки при запуске в каталоге, где раньше был неудачный запуск другой программы

Tags: python, python-3.x

Ложные сообщения об ошибках относятся к запуску программ, уже давно завершившихся и не имеющих никакой связи с текущими действиями. Единственное, что их объединяет - ложные сообщения выдаются при запуске интерпретатора в том каталоге файловой системы, где раньше был неудачный запуск другой программы. Пример:

1. Выполняю команду в домашней папке
2. Перехожу в папку *tmp*
3. Выполняю ту же самую команду - появляется сообщение об ошибке.

Вот листинг:

```
$ cd
lary@dtk58:~$ python
Python 3.5.2 (default, Nov 23 2017, 16:37:01) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from socket import *
>>> exit() 
lary@dtk58:~$ cd tmp
lary@dtk58:~/tmp$ python
Python 3.5.2 (default, Nov 23 2017, 16:37:01) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from socket import *
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/lary/tmp/socket.py", line 9, in <module>
    mysock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
NameError: name 'socket' is not defined
```

Самой программы *socket.py* там уже давно нет. Понятно, что дело в каких-то кэшах... Папку ***pycache*** в этом каталоге вычищаю - не помогает.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Вы запускаете интерпретатор python из папки `/home/lary/tmp/` в которой у вас лежит файл `socket.py`. И когда пытаетесь импортировать `socket`, то импортируете не стандартную библиотеку, а ваш файл.

Причем файл в tmp у вас есть, так интерпретатор даже дошел до 9 строки.

При импортировании python сначала ищет файлы в текущей директории, поэтому и происходит импортирование вашего файла.

P.S. Лучше всего избегать название скриптов, которые могут совпадать с названиями из стандартной библиотеки.

Comment: Да, именно так всё и было. Но почему тогда *ipython* не выдавал этой ошибки? У него другие умолчания?

Comment: Нет, не должно быть. ipython использует тот же порядок загрузки. Единственное может быть что ipython у вас запускается в другой рабочей директории.